# InitializeSecurityContext failed with SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED

Tags: windows, kerberos, single-sign-on

I have a question.
There's a client and server apps written in Java.
Java client connects to server using kerberos authentication, the client need to retrieve a token from the server - it uses Waffle library which uses JNA, which invokes InitializeSecurityContext function of SSPI API (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/nf-sspi-initializesecuritycontexta).

The InitializeSecurityContext function invocation failes with SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED exception (message: The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-error-codes-4)

The client machine is in Windows domain, the user is in this domain, it's possible to ping the domain and all its controllers.
The domain is also displayed for a network adapter (vtm.local domain).
[image: Network adapters]

Could you help me? What's the reason of the problem? Why is SEC_E_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault. The InitializeSecurityContext function was invoked with incorrect target principal. It was obvious after monitoring tcp connection between client and domain controller by wireshark tool.